# Mostrar registros asignados a un solo usuario

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Que tal cuento con la siguiente consulta para mostrarme aquellos usuarios con trabajo asignados por plantas y me esta funcionando bien el inconveniente es que en algunas ocasiones se les asigna hasta 4 racks y cuando me muestra el resultado solo me muestra un rack en ves de todos.

Consulta

```
select case 
          when cast(now() as time) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' then 'S' 
            when cast(now() as time) between '06:00:00' and '15:29:59' then 'F' 
            else 'R' 
            end TurnoActual 
            , now() FechaYHoraActual 
            , codigo_persona
            , Nombre 
            , Puesto 
            , Imagen 
            , type
            , cantidad 
            , user_name 
            , plant 
          from empleados,certificaciones,workin,meta,seriales,picking
          where turno = case 
          when cast(now() as time) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' then 'S' 
          when cast(now() as time) between '06:00:00' and '15:29:59' then 'F' 
          else 'R' 
          end and workin.employee = empleados.codigo_persona and workin.type = meta.categoria 
          and date(date_asign) = date(now()) and left(rack_location,1) = left(plant,1)
          group by Nombre
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente la columna plant es donde deberia mostrarme todas aquellas plantas asignadas

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| TurnoActual | FechaYHoraActual    | codigo_persona | Nombre                 | Puesto         | Imagen   | type       | cantidad | user_name | plant |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| F           | 2023-07-17 11:59:47 |         243654 | DIAZ GARCIA, JOSE LUIS | MONTACARGUISTA | 5761.jpg | Componente |      330 | JS25175   | D     |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Pero al revisar la tabla de workin la persona tiene asignado 6 plantas

```
+------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
| id_working | employee | plant | type       | date_asign          |
+------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
|         15 |   243654 | A     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
|         16 |   243654 | B     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
|         17 |   243654 | C     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
|         18 |   243654 | D     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
|         19 |   243654 | E     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
|         20 |   243654 | F     | Componente | 2023-07-17 08:42:33 |
+------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
```

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo mostrar estos 6 registros con mi consulta anterior de antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes una cláusula `group by` en esta consulta que no tiene llamadas a funciones de agregación?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar tu consulta utilizando la función GROUP_CONCAT() para concatenar los valores de las plantas asignadas en una sola columna. Aquí tienes el ejemplo modificado de tu consulta:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '05:59:59' THEN 'S' 
        WHEN CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '15:29:59' THEN 'F' 
        ELSE 'R' 
    END AS TurnoActual, 
    NOW() AS FechaYHoraActual,
    e.codigo_persona,
    e.Nombre,
    e.Puesto,
    e.Imagen,
    w.type,
    w.cantidad,
    w.user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(w.plant) AS plantas_asignadas
FROM empleados e
JOIN workin w ON w.employee = e.codigo_persona
JOIN meta m ON w.type = m.categoria
JOIN picking p ON p.date_asign = DATE(NOW())
JOIN seriales s ON LEFT(p.rack_location, 1) = LEFT(s.plant, 1)
WHERE w.turno = CASE 
        WHEN CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '05:59:59' THEN 'S' 
        WHEN CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '15:29:59' THEN 'F' 
        ELSE 'R' 
    END
GROUP BY e.Nombre;
```

Comment: OP habló de un **problema**. ¿Cómo responde este SQL a la pregunta? Lee [answer], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y evita usar contenido generado por GPT, ya que [**no está permitido**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".